# How to deploy flutter example for the web?

Tags: flutter, katex

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex/example (want to run this code for Flutter Web)

Goal: Deploy flutter example on a simple web page for checking latex code output

Expected result: Simple web page where you type Latex on the left and it shows you rendered equations on the right

My experience: 1 day

Current installation: Flutter, Dart, Android Studio, Dart -> Able to "create new Flutter project"

What I have tried: Opened a new flutter project - pasted code in main.dart - did not work (no device device - need virtual device for web deployment?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to run your Flutter project on the web, you must ensure that you have the latest version of Flutter (currently I am running v2.0.2). If you don't have the latest version, just run `flutter upgrade` in the terminal.

Secondly, you need to check whether the package that you are using also supports the web platform. You can check it by going into the "Scores" tab in the package.

[image: Web support]

Then, all you have to do is to run the command:

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

This will launch the flutter app in the Google chrome browser.